# Android - how do you remove Honeycomb's "zoom to fill" option for your app?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

While it's probably handy for something (though I've yet to find it helpful) the new "zoom to fill" option is appearing for my app when it is run on my Android 3.2 tablet. My app is compatible with earlier versions of Android (down to 2.1-update1). In searching for info on how to disable this, I've found tons of sites saying it can be done but not *how* it can be done! **So, how do I keep the Honeycomb "zoom to fill" option from appearing for my app?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your manifest must indicate you support tablet-sized screens: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/preparing-for-handsets.html and http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

Make sure for instance that you have:

```
android:xlargeScreens="true"
android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"
```

in your support-screens tag.

Comment: That was FAST! Thanks for the links... I can see this may be a little involved (I don't want to limit this app to tablets alone yet). What you suggest here does just that, but the other link you gave tells of making multiple layouts. I'll have to delve into it but hopefully there's a way to make the one app behave on both tablets and handsets (it appears the multiple layouts may do so).

Comment: I see I'll need to use a newer API level to properly use this, while keeping my Min API at 7 and testing against that in addition to the more current ones. Thanks again for your help! (BTW, your website came up in more than one search unrelated to this and proved helpful as well.)

Comment: So, I updated to API 13 and added only android:xlargeScreens="true" and the resize icon disappeared. However, when I added requiresSmallestWidthDp="320" (since my app supports that small a screen) the icon reappeared! Not for 600 though. I'm not sure what's up with that but simply omitting 'requiresSmallestWidthDp' appears to work fine. Thanks again for the helpful pointers!

Answer (score 1):

Set target sdk version to >= 11 if you don't want the "zoom to fill" feature, < 11 otherwise!

Comment: I appreciate the input. As above, I updated to API 13 as part of all this and it apparently was what did the trick.